# How to save tomcat console outputs in log file + display in the console itself?

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, server

I want to save tomcat console outputs in the `log` file. I did it by changing **startup.bat**

like this:

```
call "%EXECUTABLE%" run >..\logs\outputfile.log 2>&1 start %CMD_LINE_ARGS% run >..\logs\outputfile.log 2>&1
```

This method is saving all tomcat console outputs in `\logs\outputfile.log` file.
But the console itself is **not displaying outputs** .

How can I display outputs in console and in log file as well ???

Is it possible? If yes Please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just `tail -f`the log file in a second window?

Comment: Is this windows? you can achieve similar to `tail -f` using baretail or similar https://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/

Comment: @owen79 yes its WINDOWS os

Comment: @ABD then you can use baretail to tail the log file. I don't think there is anything like tee in windows